# A proof of the $QR$ algorithm when $A$ is symmetric and tridiagonal that doesn't involve shifting

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the following special case of the $QR$ algorithm:

> Let $A$ be symmetric and tridiagonal. Define the following sequence of matrices: $A_1 :=A$, and for $n \ge 1$ decompose  $A_n=Q_n R_n$ and set $A_{n+1}:= R_n Q_n$.

Most sources I came across just mention:

> It can be shown that $A_n$ converges to a diagonal matrix.

Some other sources prove it for a more general case and it quickly becomes hard to follow (e.g. shifting).

Is there a proof of this special case that doesn't involve shifting?